# how php get multiple table column value with Condition

Tags: php, mysql, join

First, thanks for your guy spend time to read this.

Now I have two table, and the data is below:

table name: table1

```
+-----------+----------+---------------------------+
| tid       | area     | Subject                   |
+-----------+----------+---------------------------+
| 1         | US       | The one restaurant        |
| 2         | US       | Landmark hotel            |
| 3         | US       | Tholo restaurant          |
| 4         | CA       | GE bar                    |
+-----------+----------+---------------------------+
```

table name: table2

```
+--------+---------+---------------------------+---------------+
| tid    | area    | Value                     | optionid      |
+--------+---------+---------------------------+---------------+
| 1      | US      | the one restaurant desc   | restaurant    |
| 1      | US      | the one rest. contact     | recontact     |
| 1      | US      | the one rest. address     | readdress     |
| 2      | US      | landmark hotel desc       | hotel         |
| 2      | US      | landmark hotel.contact    | hocontact     |
| 2      | US      | landmark hotel.address    | hoaddress     |
| 3      | US      | Tholo restaurant.desc     | restaurant    |
| 3      | US      | Tholo restaurant.contact  | recontact     |
| 3      | US      | Tholo restaurant.address  | readdress     |
| 4      | CA      | GE bar.desc               | bar           |
| 4      | CA      | GE bar.contact            | bacontact     |
| 4      | CA      | GE bar.address            | baaddress     |
+--------+---------+---------------------------+---------------+
```

I would like to show the data like below when user query area=US

```
|tid  | Subject              | description             | contact                     |    Address               |area|
+-----+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+----+
| 1   | The one restaurant   | the one restaurant desc | the one rest.contact        | the one rest.address     | US |
| 2   | Landmark hotel       | landmark hotel desc     | landmark hotel contact      | landmark.address         | US |
| 3   | Tholo restaurant     | Tholo restaurant.desc   | Tholo restaurant.contact    | Thoro restaurant.address | US |
```

Now I only can success alias and union, can't join the subject, and my code is below:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT value AS restaurant_description FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = restaurant UNION SELECT value AS restaurant_contact FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = recontact UNION SELECT value AS restaurant_address FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = readdress UNION SELECT value AS hotel FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = hotel UNION SELECT value AS hotel_description FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = hotel UNION SELECT value AS hotel_contact FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = hocontact UNION SELECT value AS hotel_address FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = hoaddress UNION SELECT value AS bar_description FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = bar UNION SELECT value AS bar_contact FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = bacontact UNION SELECT value AS bar_address FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = baaddress"); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $row['hotel_description'];
        echo $row['hotel_lat'];
        echo $row['subject'];
}
```

I have try the code below, but it cant show the data i need.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT value AS restaurant_description FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = restaurant UNION SELECT value AS restaurant_contact FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = recontact UNION SELECT value AS restaurant_address FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = readdress UNION SELECT value AS hotel FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = hotel UNION SELECT value AS hotel_description FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = hotel UNION SELECT value AS hotel_contact FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = hocontact UNION SELECT value AS hotel_address FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = hoaddress UNION SELECT value AS bar_description FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = bar UNION SELECT value AS bar_contact FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = bacontact UNION SELECT value AS bar_address FROM table2 WHERE fid = US AND optionid = baaddress UNION SELECT subject FROM table1 WHERE fid = US AND table1.tid = table2.tid");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats more like creating `pivot` table. If you only want `recontact` ,`restaurant` and  `readdress` values for each you can use the following technique.

```
select
t1.tid,
t1.subject,
t2.area,
max(case when t2.optionid = 'restaurant' then t2.Value end) as `description`,
max(case when t2.optionid = 'recontact' then t2.Value end ) as `contact`,
max(case when t2.optionid = 'readdress' then t2.Value end ) as `Address`
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.tid = t2.tid
group by t1.tid;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but when i try this with area=US, it can't show any data also,

I will request from link like this: http://www.example.com/info.php?areacode=US,
after that in the php will have a code like this,
$area = $_GET['areacode'];

how do I insert the $area in the mysql query?

Comment: You need to have where `t2.area = $area` before the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT value AS restaurant_description FROM table2 WHERE `fid` ="US" AND `optionid` = "restaurant" UNION SELECT value AS restaurant_contact FROM table2 WHERE `fid` = "US" AND `optionid` = "recontact" UNION SELECT value AS restaurant_address FROM `table2` WHERE `fid` ="US" AND `optionid` = "readdress" UNION SELECT value AS hotel FROM `table2` WHERE `fid` = "US" AND `optionid` = "hotel" UNION SELECT value AS hotel_description FROM `table2` WHERE `fid` = "US" AND `optionid` = "hotel" UNION SELECT value AS hotel_contact FROM `table2` WHERE `fid` = "US" AND `optionid` = "hocontact" UNION SELECT value AS hotel_address FROM `table2` WHERE `fid` = "US" AND `optionid` = "hoaddress" UNION SELECT value AS bar_description FROM `table2` WHERE `fid` = "US" AND `optionid` = "bar" UNION SELECT value AS bar_contact FROM table2 WHERE `fid` = "US" AND `optionid` = bacontact UNION SELECT value AS bar_address FROM `table2` WHERE `fid` ="US" AND `optionid` = "baaddress" UNION SELECT subject FROM `table1` WHERE `fid` = "US" AND `table1`.tid = `table2`.tid");
```

first change your query like this and echo it if any error it shows than let me know

Comment: if include the "UNION SELECT subject FROM `table1` WHERE `fid` = "US" AND `table1`.tid = `table2`.tid" will be blank only, if delete "UNION SELECT subject FROM `table1` WHERE `fid` = "US" AND `table1`.tid = `table2`.tid" can be work properly, but cannot show the subject.